# define a typescript type that can contain only one single property

Tags: typescript, types

I have this JSON :

```
 "meta"          : [
   {"http://example.com/rel/1/" : "my meta 14"},
   {"http://example.com/rel/2/" : "345"}
 ],
```

How can I express this in a typescript type ?

*meta* is an **array** of *meta_item* **objects**,
where each *meta_item* has only **one property**.

The **key** of *meta_item* should be an URI, the **value** can be anything.

Is this possible ?

Thanks !

Comment: I asked you in your previous question (which I've closed as a duplicate of this; I assume it's the same issue) how you define a URI, since there is no native type in TS corresponding to this; you never answered.  Is it just "a string with a `:` character in it"? Does it need to enforce all the rules for known URI schemes? What is the requirement here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I had the choice, I'd probably go for a dictionary:

```
const meta: { [id: string] : any; } = {};
meta["http://example.com/rel/1/"] = "my meta 14"
meta["http://example.com/rel/2/"] = "345"
```

Or, if you want the array:

```
type meta_item = {
  [url: string]: any;
};

meta: meta_item[];
```

Comment: Have you tried this in an IDE?  It's full of errors; the `URL` type is not a valid object key in TypeScript.

Comment: I havn't. I thought URL was built-in, a string should work just fine if you don't wanna bother.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45300968/browser-api-url-class-is-not-recognized-in-typescript
It's also possible you can't use an URL as a key, where again, just use a string.

Comment: URL is available but TypeScript doesn't want you to use it as a key.  Will you [edit] to use `string` instead so that this is usable?  I don't know if the OP cares about `string` vs valid-URI-string, but at least strings are valid key types.  I'd strongly recommend testing all code you post wherever possible so that it's doing what you think it's doing.

Comment: Thanks, it should be fixed now.